# Is Ant Design for React adheres to ARIA (X508 compliance)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Does Ant Design for React adhere to ARIA (X508 compliance), like keyboard accessibility? In my work, this is a basic requirement of a UI library. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/search?q=aria&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

yes, we do. But we haven't do a check for all components, so feel free to file an issue if you find any accessibility problem, and we will fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. We will check and if find any issues will raise bug.